# fill form using requests

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to fill a form on following url:

```
"https://mailfence.com/registration/?lg=en&back=1&nextPage=%2Fsw%3Ftype%3DL%26state%3D0%26lf%3Dmailfence"
```

I studied the request made but could not find the data fields to be submitted.
The request details are

**url** : https://mailfence.com/api/v1/account/registration/s

**method**: post

**Request header:**

```
Accept:
    application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding
    gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language:
    en-US,en;q=0.5
Cache-Control:
    no-cache
Connection:
    keep-alive
Content-Length:
    2
Content-Type:
    application/json;charset=utf-8
Cookie:
    ContactOfficeLocale=en; JSESSIONID=CFA501ED2B271E8718316FA86DB9A945
Host:
    mailfence.com
lf:
    mailfence
Origin:
    https://mailfence.com
Pragma:
    no-cache
Referer:
    https://mailfence.com/registration/?lg=en&back=1&nextPage=%2Fsw%3Ftype%3DL%26state%3D0%26lf%3Dmailfence
s:
    recovery
Sec-Fetch-Dest:
    empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode:
    cors
Sec-Fetch-Site:
    same-origin
uid:
    1bc731d5-58a8-424c-bf1f-a41cb0fe4f4a
User-Agent:
    Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:97.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/97.0
```

The request payload is a empty json. There is no response data.I dont know how to give or submit the form.

Comment: Are you trying to perform the request using cURL? This seems like a form supported by JS.

Comment: @astrochun I am simply doing post request to the url above in question

Comment: If you're trying to fill out this form using python `requests`, I don't think you can. It takes the data from the form responses, not with a payload. Otherwise, it's too easy for a bot to create an enormous amount of accounts.

Comment: @astrochun I know that and want to know how to do it without using selenium(To slow). Is is possible without browser automation

Comment: You probably can't do it without selenium

Comment: I have done it with selenium was looking for other methods for speed

Comment: If you're doing selenium, you're pretty close to end-to-end testing. How long does it take for that request to go through? End-to-end always take longer. I would just leave it to CI to do the work.

Comment: @astrecun it is about 40s for complete signup process